# My components can't render on my browser. I have seen my component render before but After i imported cssBaseline it can't render anymore

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLv2S.png)My components can't render on my browser. I have seen my component render before but After i imported cssBaseline it can't render anymore
[image]

this is my app.js
This is my component I want to render

[image: This is my map component]

When I debug it looks like this [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbPzp.png)

Comment: Do you have any console errors or have you tried not importing cssBaseline for the debug purpose to see if it really is the case affecting your component rendering?

Comment: `CssBaseline` is not used anywhere and thus has no effect.

Comment: @DorjiTshering first I have written my app but when I add that cssBaseline to fix my padding issues it can't work

Comment: @user4980215 I have removed it bcz after i added it the browser showed nothing disappeared

Comment: Errors indicate a problem in the Map component. Please, show the corresponding code.

Comment: Thank u @user4980215 I checked my map.js and finally worked